# How do I extrude an object into another creating depth?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I am designing a fader and I want to have the groove be deep. I don't know how to extrude the grey long rectangle into the white face. They are two seperate meshes and I need to show some depth for when I render with light (the fader should look like it is actually sliding in a groove).

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate but I can't find the exact one. Left an answer for now.

Answer (score 7):

Select the object you want to use to create the groove, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and press <kbd>E</kbd> and extrude it to give it some depth (as deep as you want the groove to be). Next select the panel (the white face) and add a *Boolean* modifier to it selecting the extruded object as the input, change the operation to *Difference* and then apply the modifier if you are satisfied with the results. Finally, delete the extruded object and you can enter edit mode to tweak as desired.

[image]

Comment: How do you create those keyboard references? More specifially, how to you make those boxes referencing key commands in your tutorial. This would be useful for any future answers I produce.

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist Use `<kbd></kbd>` tags to surround your text. See [this](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255/styling-for-gui-instructions) and [this](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/388/button-to-insert-kbd-kbd-for-users-with-moderator-rights). In the future, you can click _edit_ on the post to look at the underlying structure.

Comment: Thanks! That will be most useful. I love learning a new HTML tag now and then.